# How to send a PDF in email to multiple users in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

```
public function index()
{
    $data["email"] = "xyz@gmail.com";
    $data["title"] = "From Admin";
    $data["body"] = "This is Demo";

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.myTestMail', $data);

    $mail = Mail::send('emails.myTestMail', $data, function($message)use($data, $pdf) {
        $message->to($data["email"], $data["email"])
                ->subject($data["title"])
                ->attachData($pdf->output(), "Bill.PDF");
    });

    
}
```

This is my code to send email to one person. How can I fetch all the users from database and send same email to all the users? Any suggestion please?

Comment: What have you tried so far and why does it not work? Have you tried to fetch all the users and send the email to them?

Comment: show query which you have tried to get emails list

Comment: I have tried to fetch all the users using 
$users = User::all();
$emails = $users->email;
But it shows email is not available in this instance.

Comment: try  $user=App\Models\User::pluck('email'); then pass  $message->to($user->toArray())

Comment: public $user;

        public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from Admin')
                    ->view('emails.myTestMail');

    }
I have added Mail class. But not sure how to integrate this class in controller.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation on how to iterate over database rows. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table

Comment: I have studied that one but got stuck here. not getting any solution for this. I know how to fetch all the data from table. But fetching problem to integrate with the mail.

Comment: `$users->email;` makes no sense - $users is clearly a list/array (of all users!), and therefore won't have the function directly. In the simplest case maybe try `$users = User::all(); foreach ($users as $user) { $email = $user->email; /* and then send the email here */ }`